# Looking for a better algorithm for inserting into C-Style String (char *)

Tags: c, arrays, string, insert

What should be the appropriate algorithm for inserting into a `char *` buffer (C string)?

I am currently using something like described below and also with the functions (from C library) I am using to implement those
Here I am talking about C style string, not a C++ string.  I am not allowed to use that.

- Given a string S1 of N length to be inserted into another string S2 of length M at position P
- Allocate a temporary string tmp of M+N+2 length // malloc
- Also realloc S2 with M+N+2 length // realloc
- Check if allocation and reallocation is successful or not
- Copy S2 to tmp until P // memmove
- Concatenate S1 and Tmp // strcat
- Concatenate S2+P and Tmp // strcat
  I'd use strcat but with large array gives access (write) violation (strcat) so I have to write my own implementation of strcat which works fine and I am totally unaware of why it's actually doing so (access violation by strcat)   .
- Overwite S2 with Tmp // memmove

This is working, but I am working on large strings so I am looking for
any way to remove tmp and any other better
alternative to the functions I am using.  Also, is there any other optimisation for speed because I will be using it a lot?

Comment: If `S2` is of size M, you can't overwrite it with `Tmp`. I'm not sure it'll be faster but maybe you can try to use `memcpy`. Can't you also do `S2 = Tmp` instead of using `memmove` at the end ?

Comment: idk but as i remember i read somewhere that memove is more efficient then memcpy

Comment: `memmove()` checks and deals with overlapping of source and destination. `memcpy()` simply copies with no regards to overlapping. So, `memmove()` can replace all calls to `memcpy()` incurring check penalties, but `memcpy()` cannot replace (some) `memmove()` calls under penalty of invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: "Overwite S2 with Tmp" is a problematic  requirement.  Either 1) the function needs to know the size of memory associated with `S2` or `S2` needs to have been allocated memory that can be re-allocated.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that when tmp is allocated, S2 is also reallocated with M+N+2

Comment: Since you know the string lengths, you should be able to use `memmove()` only (no need for `strcat()` at all).   You haven't shown the interface to your function.  The term MCVE ([MCVE]) springs to mind.  You don't mention freeing Tmp.  You shouldn't need both Tmp and the realloc'd S2.  Simply allocate Tmp, then do the copying to Tmp, then release the old S2, and move the Tmp pointer to S2.  It means you'll be passing `char **S2` to the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are resizing the destination string S2, you don't need another buffer at all.

One possibility is:

1. Realloc to M+N+1 - number of chars from each string and one more for the terminating NUL.
2. Allowing for the possible overlap, use memmove (not memcpy) to shift everything from P:N+1 (including the original trailing NUL) up to the end of the buffer.
3. Copy the M chars from S1 into the space starting at P. There's no overlap so memcpy will work. Do not use strcpy here - you don't want the terminating NUL to be added here in the middle of your destination string.

Personally I would prefer to allocate a new buffer of the correct size, instead of reallocating the existing one. Partly because it could avoid doing the double-copy of the part of the string after P, but mainly to avoid destroying the input strings, or just crashing if they weren't allocated by malloc.

For step 2, using `void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);`, you need to move the range P : N+1 into the new position starting at P+M, so:

```
memmove(S2 + P + M, S2 + P, N - P + 1);
```

Assuming a target string of 9 chars plus 1 NUL terminator (N=9), an inserted string of 2 chars (M=2), and an insert position of 7 (P=7), this would move 9 - 7 + 1 = 3 bytes from position 7 up to position 7 + 2 = 9, leaving positions 7 and 8 free to hold the 2 new characters from the string to be inserted.

Comment: For step 2, what should be parameters to memmove, sorry but i really don't understands memmove well